# Tensorflow saving error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a python class which creates a model and a corresponding tf.Saver object:

```
self._Save_model = tf.train.Saver({"w1":self._w1, "b1": self._b1, "w2":self._w2, "b2": self._b2,"w3":self._w3, "b3": self._b3, "w4":self._w4, "b4": self._b4})
```

I then proceed to call this function (defined in the same class as above), passing it my current tensorflow Session:

```
def save_model(self,sess):
        save_path = self._Save_model.save(sess,'/checkpoints')
        return save_path
```

However, I get the following error when I make a call to the function above:

```
tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_writer.cc:123] Failed to rename file /checkpoints.tempstate9800696
```

Answer (score 3):

Nvm, turns out I just needed to specfy the checkpoint file format when saving. Changing save_model to 
`self._Save_model.save(sess,'/checkpoints' + 'model.ckpt')`
works.